Using foreach loop on Dictionary<>
When I was trying to use foreach loop with classes or a value type I was doing it like that
foreach(int item in items)
{
   //rest of the code
}

However when I tried to loop the Dictionary like that
foreach(Dictionary<TKey,TValue> item in dictionaryobject)
{
    //compile error
}

I got a compile error so I must use KeyValuePair<int, string>
foreach(KeyValuePair<int,string> item in dictionaryobject)
{
    //code
}

Why must I use KeyValuePair instead of the Dictionary?

What data type is items? I'm guessing it's something like a List<int>. A List<int> is a list of integers. Each element in the list is an int, and the collection has type "list of ints", or List<int>. Same with dictionaries: the collection is a "dictionary where each entry is an int mapped to a string", or a Dictionary<int, string>. When you loop over each element, that element isn't a whole new dictionary, it's an "int mapped to a string", which is a KeyValuePair<int, string>

Because a dictionary is a collection of key-value-pairs, not a collection of dictionaries.

Note that the dictionary has Keys & Values properties if you are only interested in one or the other.


Why must I use KeyValuePair instead of the Dictionary?

Because KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> is what the enumerator of GetEnumerator yields for each item in the dictionary. A Dictionary<TKey, TValue> implements IEnumerable(Of KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue)) and that interface needs to be implemented for foreach, so GetEnumerator is called when you use a foreach. See: Make a Visual C# class usable in a foreach statement
If you have a List<int> each int is enumerated, but in case of a dictionary you want the pair of key and value.

Regarding:
foreach(int item in items)

Assuming items is e.g. a List<int> (or similar), it makes sense to use int item in a for-each loop, because each entry in the collection is an int.
But in this line:
foreach(Dictionary<TKey,TValue> item in dictionaryobject)

Assuming dictionaryobject is a Dictionary, each element is not a Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.
Therefore the 2 lines are not correlated.
The correlative version is indeed:
foreach(KeyValuePair<int,string> item in dictionaryobject)

Because each element in a Dictionary is a KeyValuePair<int,string>.

What I know is if I want to iterate some arrays or lists I must use the same type such as class int or string to iterate it. Why that one is not how is programmed ?

You have to use the type of element that is in the container (e.g. int in your example with the array). But in a Dictionary the element type is KeyValuePair<int,string> (in your example).

Your dictionary is dictionaryobject. when iterating over it, each iteration provides a pair of key and value, not another dictionary - hence, the KeyValuePair<int,string>.

<Dictionary<TKey, TValue> is the generic Dictionary Type. If your target object was a List<Dictionary<TKey, TValue>> then this for-loop statement would indeed work.
In for-loops, you typically want to define the TYPE of data you will be looping over within the collection. As for you, your dictionaryObject has mapped types of <int, string>, that is, a dictionary mapping integer key values to string values.
Generally, in C#, when you iterate over a dictionary, the foreach loop processes each key-value pair in the dictionary as KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>. This allows you to access both the key and the value for each entry during iteration. A dictionary is simply, a collection of key-value pairs, and KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> is the TYPE of pair within your collection.
